# Oracle workspace manager DBMS_WM.COMMITDDL takes long time to finalize changes

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm relatively new to using oracle workspace manager in 12c.

Have made DDL changes to version enabled table.  To finalize the changes the below command is taking almost 45 minutes.  Any tips to improve the execution time?

```
EXEC DBMS_WM.COMMITDDL(<tbl_name>);
```